# Get full datepicker date when mouse hover it Jquery/Java-Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to get a full date in the form: `06/23/2014`. Right now i am just getting the current date i.e `23`.

**Markup:**

```
<label for="pickDate"/>
<input type="text" id="pickDate"/>
```

**Script:**

```
$(function()
{
    $("#pickDate").datepicker();
    $(".ui-state-default").live("mouseenter", function()
    {
        $("h1").text($(this).text());
    });
});
```

**JsFiddle:**

[`Date Picker on hover`](http://jsfiddle.net/EsWzp/1/)

Comment: you want a static date of today or always the date that is being hovered over?

Comment: I recommend checking this out for constructive reading:http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate

Comment: @webeno this 'always the date that is being hovered over'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use event delegation to attach the mouse enter to every dynamically appended days on the date picker.

Then you can get the hovered day text and the current month/year displayed.

Code:

```
var monthname = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

$(function () {
    $("#pickDate").datepicker();
    $("body").on("mouseenter", ".ui-state-default", function () {
        $("h1").text(monthname.indexOf($(".ui-datepicker-month").text()) + 1 + "/" + $(this).text() + "/" + $(".ui-datepicker-year").text());
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/LuS4C/

Comment: hey thanks to you too. this is another way of getting the full date.

Comment: @user3400389 You are welcome; I think the accepted answer not will work on month/year change, give a try on it

Comment: i donot want to change the tick mark as i already marked it, but yeah your code right now is the best one so far. and simple too. iwill amke that code perfect too. again thanks to you. i voted up your answer

Comment: @user3400389 - you should accept the best answer, even if it means unaccepting another answer, and the currently accepted answer isn't even close, `.datepicker('getDate');` get's the selected date not the hovered date, so I don't really see how it's relevant.

Answer (score 2):

The date is available from each buttons data attributes if you use a current version of jQuery and jQuery UI, and not something that was deprecated five years ago.

```
$(function() {
    $("#pickDate").datepicker();
    $(document).on('mouseenter', 'td[data-handler="selectDay"]', function() {

        var day   = $(this).text();
        var month = $(this).data('month');
        var year  = $(this).data('year');

        $("h1").text( day + '/' + (month+1) + '/' + year );
    })
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/EsWzp/212/)

Comment: month should be `month+1`

Comment: @user3400389 - You're right, months are zero based in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to build the date. You can use this code as reference...

```
function getToday() {
            var d = new Date();
            var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
            var day = d.getDate();

            var output = d.getFullYear() + '-' + (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' + (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day;

            return output;
        }
```

Comment: this is for the current day-year right?

Comment: it needs to be adapted to your situation - I'm working on a complete answer for you though...

Comment: thanks for making an effort.

Comment: actually, Irvin's answer is perfect - you should use that one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need:

```
var v = $('#pickDate').datepicker('getDate');
```

Now, you hava a javascript date object and you can use the standard functions found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) to extract the parts of the date you need.

It would be something like:

```
if (v != null) {
     var d = (v.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + v.getDate() + '/' + v.getFullYear()
}
```

Comment: My apologies! I clumsily used the same variable name twice, make sure to change them up.

Comment: Also, you might want to do a check to make sure the date isn't null before you try and access the attributes...I'll modify the code in place for you:

Comment: Check out your modified fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/EsWzp/205/

Comment: @ deweyredman hey thankyou so much u already helped me alot. i got it +1

Comment: I'll concede that Irvin's answer is much better than mine.  I hastily looked up how to get the Date from the API and went from there.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone here loves doing the extra work it seems

```
 <script>
                $(function() {
             $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: \'2013:2015\' }).val();

                      });
                       </script>';
```

This will get you enough options to mess with I hope.

Comment: i remembered using this in my code a while ago. The only thing i love about stackoverflow. multiple ways of doing the same thing :)

Comment: Did you even read the question and the other answers ?